# プログラミングCの再帰に関しての質問です。

Tags: c, アルゴリズム

Cの初心者です。
再帰を使用して、ユーザーが入力した自然数（入力される自然数の数は分からない）をscanfで読み取り、その中から最大値を返す関数int max()を書くという課題です。ユーザーが入力する最後の自然数は0でなくてはならず、0が入力されたら関数は必ず終了し、その時点での最大値を返す。

配列やリスト、ループを使わずに再帰だけで書かなければならず、以下のコードではどうも毎回入力した一つ目の数字だけを返すのですが、何時間格闘しても原因がわかりません。

しょうもない質問かもしれませんが、ご指摘、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max() {
    int i;
    int result = 0;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i > result) {
        result = i;
        return result;
    }
    if (i < result)
        return result;
    if (i == 0)
        exit(0);

    return max();
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter your numbers (the last one should be zero):\n");
    printf("The maximum value is %d.\n", max());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

max() がどういう動作をするか、頭から追いかけていけば、原因が分かります。

max() が最初に呼び出されると、

1. 変数 i が作成される
2. 変数 result が作成され、0　に初期化される。
3. scanf で自然数が i に読み込まれる。　ここでユーザは 5 を入力したと仮定します。つまり i は 5 になります。
4. i と result, つまり 5 と 0 を比べるので、最初の if 文の中身が実行される。
5. result に i を代入し、5 になる。
6. `return result;` で 5 を返して max() 関数から抜け出す。

でおしまいです。6. のところでは、再帰的に max() を呼ぶ必要があります。

その他、気づいた点をいくつか。

1. 変数の result は、max()を呼び出すたびに新しく作成されます。つまり、最初の max()と、そこから呼び出したmax()は、それぞれ別の result なので、結果を取っておくのには使えません。結果を比較するには戻り値を利用しましょう。
2. exit()はプログラム自体をいきなり終了します。`i==0`は、再帰の終了条件なので、普通に関数から抜けてください。

---

**考え方**
ユーザーが1,3,0と入力した場合の考え方を説明します。

1. 最初の max() 呼び出し: 1を受け取って、再帰呼び出し
2. 二番目の max() 呼び出し: 3を受け取って、再帰呼び出し
3. 三番目の max() 呼び出し: 0を受け取ったので、0を返して関数を抜ける。
4. 二番目の max() に戻る: 自分の持っている3と、返ってきた0を比べて、大きいほうの3を返して関数を抜ける。
5. 最初の max() に戻る: 自分の持っている1と、返ってきた3を比べて、大きいほうの3を返して関数を抜ける。

これで最大値の3が返ってきます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。6. に関してなのですが、最後のreturn max();で再帰的に呼び出していることにはならないのでしょうか？また、再帰終了条件の際に関数から抜けるにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: @akakengo return は、まさに関数から抜けるための文です。ですので、最後の`return max();`にたどり着く前に 6.のところで関数を終了してしまっているのです。また再帰終了条件の時に関数から抜けるには、returnを使います。

Comment: なるほど。今回のmax関数の返り値はintに設定しているので再帰終了条件の時に関数から抜ける際にreturn;だとエラーになってしまうと思うのですが、この点に関してはどう対処すれば良いのでしょうか？なんどもすみません。

Comment: @akakengo 考え方を回答に追加したので、そちらをご覧ください。

Comment: @Hidekiさん、考え方完全に間違っていました。。とても分かりやすい解説ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

Hideki さんの回答でほぼ良いと思うのですが、疑似コードで書いてみました。
 (再帰で書くより、ループが簡単なのですが、、、)

```
int max(int lastMax) {
   // lastMax : 今までの最大値
   読み込んだ数値: i
   if (i == 0)  return lastMax;
   return max(i と lastMax の大きい方);
}

int main() {
    ...
    printf("The maximum value is %d.\n", max(0));  // 自然数の最小値: 0
    ...
}
```

Comment: @greenteaさん、そうですよねどう考えてもループで書く方が簡単ですよね。回答非常に役に立ちました、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

試しに作成してみました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int i) {
    int j;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 0) return i;
    return (i > (j=max(i)) ? i : j);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    printf("Enter your numbers (the last one should be zero):\n");
    printf("The maximum value is %d.\n", max(0));
    return 0;
}
```